# Extending matrix class to support complex<double>

Tags: c++, templates, variables

I have a class for storing real matrices. But I would like to extend it to support complex matrices as well (for example, by using std::complex type). I think about templates at the moment (but I haven't studied them enough yet). Is there a way to make this class generic without rewriting too much code?

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class matrix {
protected:
    int nRows;
    int nCols;
    double** arr;

public:
    matrix::matrix();
    matrix::matrix(int rows, int cols, bool random);
    matrix::matrix(const matrix& m);
    matrix::~matrix();
    static matrix ident(int n);
    matrix getRow(int rowIndex) const;
    matrix getColumn(int colIndex) const;
    matrix transpose() const;
    void exchangeRows(int row1, int row2);
    double get2Norm() const;

private:
    void initParams();
    void fillRandom();
protected:
    void initArray(int rows, int cols);
    void deallocateArray();
public:
    virtual std::string getType();
    std::string printMatrixInfo(bool withSize);
    void printMatrix() const;
    int getMinElem() const;
    int getMaxElem() const;

public:
    matrix& operator=(const matrix& m);
    bool operator==(const matrix& b);
    matrix& operator+=(const matrix& m);
    matrix& operator^=(const matrix& m);
    matrix& operator*=(double num);
    matrix operator+(const matrix& b);
    matrix operator^(const matrix& b);
    friend matrix operator*(const matrix& b, double num);
    friend matrix operator*(double num, const matrix& b);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix& m);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, matrix& m);
public:
    // const после определения функции означает, что мы
    // "обещаем" компилятору не изменять члены объекта класса
    double getElemAt(int i, int j) const
    {
        return (i >= 0 && i < nRows&& j >= 0 && j < nCols ? arr[i][j] : DBL_MAX);
    }
    int getCols() const { return nCols; }
    int getRows() const { return nRows; }
    void setElemAt(int i, int j, double val) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < nRows && j >= 0 && j < nCols)
            arr[i][j] = val;
    }
};
```

Comment: You should study templates enough.

Comment: converting class to template would solve that.  You also should look into move semantics. And there is common practice to use operator() for accessing matrix members.

Comment: `template <typename T> class matrix {`, and where you see `double`, replace it with `T`.

Comment: Structuring a matrix as double pointer indirection avoids multiplication. This made sense in the past where multiplication took longer than the extra memory lookup. But outside of some very old microprocessors, it's now much slower.